# Не отправляются письма с моего домена

Tags: email

при попытке отправить с моего почтового ящика с моим доменом  - получаю вот такое сообщение об ошибке. Как быть? Впервые таким занимаюсь. использую Fastpanel.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы переходили по адресу указанного в сообщении? Читали что там пишут?

Comment: да, там сказано что нужно внести домен под контроль спамма гугла. я внес. но письма все равно не шлет(

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А что это за почта вообще, до того, как она на твоём домене стала?

Answer (score 0):

Может уже поздно, но в `fastpanel` есть кнопка настройки `DNS` перед настройкой самой почты. Там написано название `DNS TXT` и Ключ. Его необходимо занести в Ваш `DNS` (домен). После этого заработает отправка.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Если у тебя есть IMAP POP3 то можно использовать другие потовые сервисы например майл ру или mail.ee(не реклама)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]